# Euro sign not showing on site

Tags: php, mysql, html

One of my fields (which is a latin1_swedish_ci) seems to show the euro symbol fine in PHPMYADMIN inside of the field.

However, when I try to echo it in an input field on my website in a form, it shows up as the question-mark in firefox.

Heres the html/php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `settings`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $setting[$row['field']] = htmlspecialchars($row['value'], ENT_QUOTES);

<input type="text" name="currency_symbol" id="currency_symbol" size="50" value="<?php echo $setting['currency_symbol']; ?>" />
```

I am using the following meta tag on the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I've tried using utf8_general_ci for the field, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead of `htmlspecialchars()`.

Special chars does not convert everything, just a few select characters.  The Euro symbol €, needs to be encoded really, `&euro;`.

Comment: -1 The Euro sign most certainly does not need to be converted to an entity when the character set supports it. In fact, when using Unicode, you virtually never need `htmlentities` instead of `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Depends if you have setup your language and character code correctly for the document.  Firefox does have a tendency to display question marks, particularly for content inserted dynamic unless entity encoded.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Additionally, few people output as Unicode from PHP, so such things get corrupted.  PHP still does not handle that automatically, so in practice it is rarely done.

Comment: If you don't have those things setup correctly, then your process is broken, and htmlentities is an ugly hack around the actual problem - namely that you don't have those things set up correctly. I've used UTF-8 with PHP for years now, and not once has htmlentities been necessary.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Depends which standard you are keeping to, if you are still on HTML4, then it is correct procedure.  XHTML upwards, entities are a highly compatible way of dealing with the situation, some readers, like text readers, mess up UTF8 still sometimes.  Not debating that it is a sensible method, only that the older method is not "wrong".

Answer (score 4):

If you are serving the page as UTF-8, you will need to ensure you grab the string out of the database in the UTF-8 encoding before putting it on the page. You can do that using:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

(If you're doing that it would also make sense to store your actual table data in UTF-8 too, eg `utf8_general_ci`, rather than `latin1_swedish_ci`, so you can deal properly with characters outside of the basic Latin-1 set.)

Comment: That worked in my case while  htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() did not

Comment: That should solve the actual problem and is better than avoiding the problem with htmlentities().

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the [MySQL charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to UTF-8 or to Swedish.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php#83717) it is a small example.