# Euro sign converted to question mark

Tags: php, html, database, utf-8

I have an euro sign in the database. When I want to print it out on my website it is showing a question mark.

It's from text field --> database --> website.

Comment: You're not using UTF-8 everywhere, but you haven't remotely provided enough information.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810587/euro-sign-not-showing-on-site

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: aside from the DB you may need to look at the encoding header of your HTML output.

Comment: @MattBall its a bit late, but thank you :) it makes sense now so many years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is not UTF-8.

This may help:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

Or this query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Also, include this `<meta />` tag in the `<head>` of your HTML page:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: best to do both, also ensure the browser interprets the sent html also as UTF-8, therefore you can send an http header and/or add a html head field for the content type